# Construction a measure in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ and $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Find
a measurable set $E \subset [0, 1]$ such that the closure of $E$ is $[0, 1]$ and
$m(E) = \epsilon$.

Having trouble on where to start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: What the closure of $\mathbb Q \cap (0,1)$, and what is the measure?

Comment: The measure of this set is zero.

Comment: Yes, but it's quite easy to go from there to a set with measure $\epsilon$, without affecting the closure.

Comment: I can't see that directly, can you elaborate on this, please?

Comment: @Ilya How about the union of this set with $(0,\epsilon)$?

Comment: @drhab, exactly what I was thinking. I just didn't want to give the complete answer away.

Comment: I understand, but you are made free from elaborating now ;)+1.

Comment: Indeed, for some reason I though the set must be nowhere dense, otherwise the question seemed too easy to me. +1

Comment: My first thoughts also was that some elaborate construct would be needed, but then that set appeared in my mind.